# After a reboot wifi is not working. Dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

When I reboot my laptop  I can't connect to a wifi network. Most of the network options are then greyed out.

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
```

i disabled Sleep NIC in windows, but still not solved.
I also tried copying the `iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25-30.13.0 to the lib/firmware` but still not solved.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a known issue. It seems like some wifi adapters don't completely poweroff when rebooting. Your best option is to fully shutdown your computer when switching between Windows and Ubuntu.